# How do I create a PDF directly from code?

Tags: pdf

Is there an IDE (that preferably uses C), that allows me to output the results of a program onto a PDF?
I am tasked with writing a program that does a specific set of computations in which the results of each individual computation needs to be output onto a PDF file that can be opened later normally. Is there an IDE that would allow me to do such a thing? I'm currently using Codeblocks and I'm not sure whether it can do what I need as I'm not too familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is simply how to printout your code as a PDF most if not all IDEs can do that via printing.

If its how to hand write a pdf with an ID Editor you need to learn how to hand code a pdf first.

However for code::blocks see `2.14 Source Code Exporter` in the PDF User Manual